# php - automatically create an instance of myClass

Tags: php, class, instance

I have a class called myClass in  /myDir/myClass.php.  When user types url:

```
http://mysite.com/myDir/myClass.php,
```

I want to automatically create an instance of myClass. What technique can I use to do this? the idea is to use myDir directory as top level of programs that user can call directly, but I don't want to add `instance_of_myClass = new myClass();` because then I won't be able to extend the class.  Does this make sense?

```
class myClass
{    
  __construct()
  {
     echo "hello World";
     $this->myClass_report();
  }
  myClass_report()
  {
      // some code here
  }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.htaccess:

```
#if You have access, omit RewriteBase and put the rule in http.conf,
#with a / in the beginning of the pattern.
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $0 !=index.php
RewriteRule .* index.php?path=$0 [QSA,B]
```

index.php

```
//check if the file exists and it's allowed
if (!check_if_allowed_path(realpath($_GET['path']))) {
    //access denied; check e.g. against the document root or
    //something more complex
}
//or use autoload instead
include $_GET['path'];
$classname = basename($_GET['path'], '.php');
$instance = new $classname();
```

Comment: this sounds like what I what I am looking for, but will my post variables fall off?

Comment: @bob The POST content will be untouched by this.

Comment: $classname = str_replace(".php", "", basename($_GET['path']));

Answer (score 0):

```
class myClass
{    
  __construct()
  {
     echo "hello World";
     myClass_report();
  }
  myClass_report()
  {
      // some code here
  }


} 

$x = new myClass();
```

Comment: ...but I don't want to add instance_of_myClass = new myClass(); because then I won't be able to extend the class

Answer (score 0):

If you are not creating an instance with

```
$classINstance = new myClass();
```

Then you don't have a class instance. That has nothing to do with extending a class.

You extend a class (i assume you mean inheritance?), then you create a new class that extends a parent class. To use this class you also create a new instance with the new operator.

At least if you are not using the static keyword to create static methods for a class.

I had a quick search, maybe have a look at this questions accepted answer. Lookd like a good summary that could help you:

[OOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035449/why-is-oop-hard-for-me)

Or i just didn't understand what you meant ;)

Comment: fascinating thread! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035449/why-is-oop-hard-for-me

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you're trying to do, but maybe this will help:

If you want to create an instance of `myClass`, but don't want the `new myClass` to be hard-coded everywhere, you could use a [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28software_concept%29) (wikipedia) of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

Use the factory design pattern:

```
<?php
//Factory.php
include_once('Box.php');

class My_Factory
{
  private $this->outcome;

  public function __construct()
  {
    this->outcome = $this->doSomeWeirdShitToSetupTheFactoryAndBlueprintSomething();
  }

  private function doSomeWeirdShitToSetupTheFactoryAndBlueprintSomething()
  {
    //1+1
  }

  public function giveMeAnInstanceOfOutcome()
  {
    return new My_Box($this->outcome);
  }
}
```

Edit: I read it again and I have one question:
Why do you want a user to type http://yourl/YourClass.php ???

Classes should be included; never ever ever used to load directly to the browser.

Comment: can I combine this idea with a factory pattern?

Comment: "never ever ever used to load directly" - you seem to know what you are talking about, but I am bot sure why?  I am trying to move to pure OO paradigm, so I said OK, I will make all top level controllers as instances of a class.

Comment: Because your class is your blueprint. If you create a new invention you'd rather sell the product than the blueprint. All your classes should be instantiated in one file: your index.php. You bootstrap some prework and then classes do the work and even output your page.

Comment: OK. this is what I am doing now in index.php